# Getting a Light Vector on a Quad

Tags: c#, math, vector, unity-game-engine

If I have a quad, consisted of 6 vertices, how would I get the projection of a light vector onto that plane of those 6 vertices?

I'm currently having 6 vertices,  two quads,
The points are
A  X  C
B  Y  D

Point X, Y are coming from two ray casting downwards.

```
C =  X + RightVector
D =  Y +  RightVector
A =  X- RightVector
B =  Y - RightVector
```

Now I want to translate the vertices based on lightDirectionVector, how would I do that ?
I have a directional light, and that mesh of the two quads acting as a shadow quad.

```
        Vector3 lightDir = mDirectionalLight.transform.forward;
        Vector3 normLight = lightDir.normalized;
        normaLight.y = 0;
```

Comment: add some image of what exactly you want this makes no sense (at least to me take in mind not everyone here is fluent in English). btw isn't quads only from 4 points ?

Comment: @Spektre I have a mesh that has two quads, but two shared vertices, so its the mesh is a plane of 6 vertices [  ]. I just want to project the light vector onto that plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some definitions first

- I will use 4-points quad instead of your 6 but the principle is the same
- I see it like this:

[image: light projection]

- P0,...,P3 dark brown is the Quad (points on the same plane I assume)
- L is light direction vector yellow
- N is Quad normal vector blue
- D is the projected points shift vector green
- Q0,...,Q3 are projected points light brown
- - multiply
- (A.B) scalar multiply
- A x B vector multiply

OK now how to do it:

```
N' = (P1-P0) x (P2-P1); // or any other non-zero vector combination.
N = N' / |N'|;           // it is better if normal is unit vector
L = L' / |L'|;           // the same goes for light
// now you need some temporary vector n which is L projected onto N
n = N * (N.L)
// now the shift direction (lie on the Quad plane)
D' = L - N
// and now scale by d - perpendicular distance of Quad or point to projection source (light)
D = D' * d
// the rest is easy
Qi = Pi + D
```

- d - parameter could also be the distance of Quad/point to projection plane it depends on what you do exactly ...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I would like to know why I must project the light onto the plane If I just want to translate the vertices of the plane based on light direction, isn't dot product and knowing the cosine angle is enough?  Also how the light vector its direction is outwards not inwards. Would you please recommend me some books or anything to know these things in details ?

Comment: @Andre You did not provide enough info about your case so as I wrote before I assumed what you have/need. You need to tweak it to meet your needs or add necessary info. Your question is about projecting light vector onto Quad/plane so that is why. btw that n equation is your cosine in vector form. For books I do not know any good in English. You will suffice with basic 3D vector math and clear mind.